# How do I know if an async method call changes the caller's context?

Tags: c#, async-await, ui-thread

Consider this example:

```
async Task Foo()
{
    button.Text = "This is the UI context!";

    await BarA();

    button.Text = "This is still the UI context!";

    await BarB();

    button.Text = "Oh no!"; // exception (?)
}

async Task BarA()
{
    await Calculations();
}

async Task BarB()
{
    await Calculations().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

How do I know if calling `await BarB()` changes the context *without* reading the body of the `async Task BarB()` function? Do I really need to know exactly whether an async function calls `ConfigureAwait(false)` at any point? Or maybe the example is wrong and there's no exception?

Comment: "maybe the example is wrong and there's no exception?" - maybe you could compile and run the code and find out? Showing us an example and not even knowing whether it exhibits a behaviour you're wanting to ask about make for a *bad* question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What `BarB()` does is largely irrelevant, unless `BarB()` needs to talk to the UI. The important part here is the `await` in the line:

```
await BarB();
```

it is *that `await`* which captures context (too) - and negotiates getting *back* onto the correct context if it finds itself continuing from the *wrong* context. So; unless you write:

```
await BarB().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

you should be fine here.

The `ConfigureAwait(false)` in `BarB()` looks normal and is *probably* correct, if we assume that `BarB()` doesn't need to directly update the UI or perform any other context-bound operation.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement [Marc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54669180/15498) - bear in mind that `async` is an *implementation detail* of a method. How or why a method creates a `Task` that it hands back to you are largely transparent (and that's why `async` isn't part of the signature, not allowed in interface definitions, etc)

Whilst it's true that your method shares it's "current context" with methods it calls, that's only to the extent that those methods, if they want to know the current context, will call `SynchronizationContext.Current`. They'll then use methods *on* that context to get "back on it" if necessary. Any "changes" to the context will usually actually be performed by *switching continuations onto a suitable thread that already has the right context set*.

What these methods *won't* normally do is call [`SetSynchronizationContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.setsynchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_SynchronizationContext_SetSynchronizationContext_System_Threading_SynchronizationContext_). It's only if a method does call that that you have to worry about changes to "your" context. (Some infrastructure code may call that method if their synchronization context is free-threaded but requires other ambient resources. They'll get a thread pool thread, call `SetSynchronizationContext`, execute the continuation and then unset the synchronization context again).